# Method whereDate does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

- Laravel Version: 5.3.28
- PHP Version: 7.0.10
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7.14

I got an error ,When i try to use whereDate in my view page.

> 1/2 BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method whereDate
>   does not exist.
>
> 2/2 ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method whereDate does not
>   exist. (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\2_Work\dashboard\resources\views\pdf\user.blade.php)

My model relationship is work, But why i can't use whereDate function.

```
@extends('layouts.pdf')

@section('content')
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="545">
    <tr>
      <th>ชื่อผู้ใช้งาน</th>
      <th>เข้าใช้ล่าสุด</th>
      <th>จำนวนการเข้าใช้งานใน 7 วัน</th>
      <th>จำนวนงานที่ทำในวันที่ 13/01/2560</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
      <tr>
        <td><span class="td-text">{{$user->user_detail}}</span></td>
        <td align="center">{{$user->ual->first()->created_at ?? NULL}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{$user->ual->where('created_at', '>=', '(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)')->count()}}</td>
        <td align="left"><?php var_dump( $user->dataDetail->whereDate('created_at', '2017-01-13')->toArray() ); ?></td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
@endsection
```

Controller

```
$data['users'] = UserModel::all();
return view('pdf.user', $data);
```

UserModel

```
class UserModel extends Model
{
  public function dataDetail()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DataDetailModel', 'user_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your model? What is ```$user->dataDetail```?

Comment: what's you laravel version?

Comment: @SSuhat V5.3.28

Comment: Have you tried ```$user->dataDetail()->whereDate('created_at', '2017-01-13')->toArray();```?

Comment: @CUGreen Oh that is, But it must add ->get() to use this `$user->dataDetail()->whereDate('created_at', '2017-01-13')->get()->toArray();`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to use `$user->dataDetail()` with parenthesis so you can uitilise Query Builder.

**Edit:** As you mentioned in your comment, you will also need to add `get()` to access the collection.

So `$user->dataDetail()->whereDate('created_at', '2017-01-13')->get()->toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

I think u had missed the 3rd params of whereDate

Pls try this one

```
if(isset($user->dataDetail)) {
       var_dump($user->dataDetail->whereDate('created_at','=' ,'2017-01-13')->get()->toArray());
 }
```